# Check permissions before getting object in Django REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using the Django REST framework, I use this view and permission to allow only project owners to get their projects.

view.py

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (
       IsProjectOwner, 
       permissions.IsAuthenticated,
       )

    def get_queryset(self):
       return Project.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

permissions.py

```
class IsProjectOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

When an user tries to get a project which does not belong to him, a HTTP 404 arises. However, I would like to get HTTP 403_Forbidden. Here is the test I use

```
    def test_auth_get(self):
        self.client.credentials(
            HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=self.authenticated_user_token
            ) 

        response = self.client.get(
            '/-/projects/%s/' % self.project_owner_project_id
            )

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

I tried to solve the problem using a get_object() method like in the REST docu http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions. But I am not sure how to check the permission before knowing the actual object.

Comment: But a 404 is better than a 403, It doesn't expose the fact "that the object does exist but is inaccessible"

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to overide your get_queryset method;
Actually you view find object from queryset you are passing from get_queryset method.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.action == 'update':
        return Project.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
    else:
        return Project.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get_queryset` method will already limit the Project list to the ones where is owner is the current user. This will work for lists but also to retrieve or update a project.

You don't need a permission on top of that.

Comment: Sure, there is no object that fulfils the filter requirements. But I want the HTTP response to be 'forbidden' instead of 'page not found'. Do you have an idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Then you shouldn't filter in the get_queryset so that the get_object_permission is called.

Comment: Note that this will require that *you* handle the finer grained filtering on the list action.